# VS 2019 - Include an empty folder when publishing project to web

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I've created a C# ASP.Net web API project that requires 2 folders to exist in the remote server in order for the API to run:

1. "UserFiles"
2. "UserFiles/PurgeFiles"

Following the advice given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765877/1693085) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059921/1693085), I've added this to my `API.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="CreateUserFilesFolder" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)UserFiles" Condition="!Exists('$(ProjectDir)UserFiles')" />
</Target>
```

To try and create the **UserFiles** directory, for example, but it doesn't work.

I've tried updating it to `Directories="$(PublishDir)UserFiles"` and even `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)UserFiles` figuring that was the issue, but it's still not creating the empty folder.

What should the lines in my `.csproj` look like or do I, perhaps, have to define `PublishDir` or something similar somewhere to get this to work?

Comment: Methinks you need that `<Target>` in your `.pubxml` file instead (`.pubxml` files are also MSBuild files, just like `.csproj` files). However I think having the publish-process create the folder is a bit flakey (simply because the VS "Publish Project" tooling loves to completely overwrite any changes I make to it), is there a reason your application can't create the directories in your `Startup` class or `Program.Main` method?

Comment: I guess there really isn't any reason for not including it in the `Startup` method, this just seemed to be the advice given in multiple solutions I found and I just can't get it to work.  As for placing it in the `.pubxml` file, I can try that, but what would the lines to add look like? Would I still need to include the `AfterTargets="AfterPublish"` for example?

Comment: @Dai, I did put it into my `startup` class and it worked a charm! - Thank you... It's not what the other answers recommended, but it definitely did work. Thanks!!!